Overset/Overlapping Plots pgfplots
I would like to make some KPI charts using LaTeX.
I have some dummy data which pops my budget and spend adjacent to each other.
However, I would like to make the budget a wider box with no fill and a red outline and super impose the spend over this.  I found a snipped using tzplot but I'll have to work out how to annotate that and build the rest of the graphic unless I can convince these plots to appear differently and overlap.  This kind of thing is possible in excel and Matlab but I didn't see for LaTeX yet.

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tzplot}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        ymin=0,
        legend image code/.code={
            \draw[#1, draw=none] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.6cm,0.1cm);
        },  
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.10)},
          anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
        ylabel={(£)},
        symbolic x coords={Dept},
        xtick=data,
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align={vertical}
        ]
    \addplot coordinates {(Dept,2) };%Budget
    \addplot coordinates {(Dept,1) };%Spend
    \legend{Budget,Spend}
    \end{axis} 
     
    
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Budget Vs Spend}
\end{figure}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8]
    \tzplot[ybar](1,1);
    \tzplot[ybar,bar width=2mm,fill,red!50](1,2);
    (3pt)
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}


With bar shift=0pt to overlay the data.
code
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
% \usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

% \begin{figure}[t]
%     \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        bar shift=0pt,%<-- added
        ymin=0,
        legend image code/.code={
            \draw[#1, draw=none] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.6cm,0.1cm);
        },  
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.10)},
          anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
        ylabel={(£)},
        symbolic x coords={Dept},
        xtick=data,
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align={vertical}
        ]
    \addplot [fill=gray!10,bar width=0.8cm]coordinates {(Dept,1) };%Spend
    \addplot [fill=red!50]coordinates {(Dept,2) };%Budget
    \legend{Budget,Spend}
    \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
%     \caption{Budget Vs Spend}
% \end{figure}

\end{document}


